# How to embed data (file) in .resx resource file in .NET 6 (ASP.NET)?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, resx

I noticed, in .NET Framework, it is possible to 'embed' image data directly into a .resx file with the 'properties' windows within Visual Studio (22).

This is not possible in .NET 6.

- Is this intentional/by design, as in, "that feature is not included in .NET 6 (core)" ?
- Why in FW 4.8, it is packed into System.Drawing.Bitmap but in Core byte[] ??
- For FW 4.8: is this only possible for resources of type "image" (dropdown) ? I'd like to embed json(text) or binary data in the .resx file - just like with the bitmap data, directly, and not use "linked at compile time". (see bottom of post)
- is "Embedded in .resx" even at all possible for .NET 6+ ?
- does it even matter? as if I've correctly understood, all .resx is converted to .resource anyway ??

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

Reason why I'd like that:
VS has a very annoying "feature": Opening a .json in VS encoded in Codepag1252 format with culture specific chars, will cause VS to present a warning and IMMEDIATELY, AUTOMATICALLY replace those chars with GIBBERISH. If you accidentally ignore the warning, or press F5, saving the project will FOREVER, IRREVERSIBLY CORRUPT the json data. Lucky are those who have backups!
I's beyond my, why VS does this. Especially since there is an RMB option, "open with encoding", which does not do this, but plain old double-click will.

Imho, the IDE should never replace any chars without asking for permission! Especially not when simply double-clicking in the solution explorer on some random file. (btw other posts about the windows language settings didn't prevent that for me.)

In any case, the data, once embedded, would be 'safe', in comparison to corrupted data, linked at compile time.

Sidenote: After examining that behaviour, I've already converted the encoding to UTF-8, which is probably the best way to go about this specific problem, nevertheless it opened up the question about embedding.

Thanks!